# Login time of Login-Screen is not correct?

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

There seems to be a Problem with the last Login Time showed on the Login Screen.

Sometimes when I login, on the Screen the Time is wrong.

I checked the Log in the Event viewer, and the Time there is as I logged in the last Time(as I remember) and not as the Login Screen wrongly showed.

Maybe someone have had the same Issue, and knows what could be the cause ?

Comment: Is your system clock set correctly?  Including time zone?

Comment: Yes, those Settings are correct.

Comment: Do you know maybe, where these informations are stored ?